# Click Columns Multiple Dimension Measures in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi-desktop, dimension, measure

I working on migrating from Tableau to PowerBI. But I got stuck for multiple dimension.

I have a category, Budget and Revenue, I want to display a chart like below. But the issue is I cannot click each column to show a detail.
I added 1 axis Category and I want to add one more is Budget and Revenue to show filter for Year and Month.

I attached image. Hope to be help . Thank you so much

[image]